# POS tagging in nltk

Tags: python, text, nltk

Hi is there an efficient way for tagging parts of speech in very large files?

```
 import pandas as pd
 import collections 
 import nltk 

 tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(pandas_dataframe)
 tag1=nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
 counts=collections.counter([y for x,y  in tag1])
```

I am trying to find the most common parts of speech in a file and don't know of a better way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

Typically you need to get around the for loop, possible high memory load and possible high CPU load.

Here's an example of [distributed part of speech tagging](http://streamhacker.com/2009/11/29/distributed-nltk-execnet/) using python and execnet.